# iOS Crittercism & Salesforce Mobile SDK Sync Issues

Tags: objective-c, salesforce, crittercism, salesforce-ios-sdk

I have a native iOS Mobile application (xCode 7.2, iOS 9) that has the salesforce mobile SDK (v.3.3.1) integrated and configured to sync a number if soups with Salesforce.

When I try to use Crittercism (v.5.4.0) and enable it, the Saleforce Soup SycnUp/SyncDown no longer works.  Soup tables fail to create or soups cannot be found.

Any suggestions on what the conflict is?  Without Crittercism running the salesforce components work fine.

Answer (score 2):

please try upgrading to Crittercism 5.4.11.  This release includes a bug fix that was affecting certain use cases of NSURLSession.

http://docs.crittercism.com/release_notes/release_notes_ios.html#version-5-4-11-dec-23-2015